# VSCode not using test database for Django tests

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I've got an issue where VSCode's test feature uses the production database instead of creating a test database.
tests.py

```py
from django.test import TestCase
# For VSCode test discovery
from django import setup
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testing.settings")
setup()

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_some_test(self):
       SomeModel.objects.create()
       my_model = SomeModel.objects.all()
       assert len(SomeModel.objects.all()) == 1
```

I have previously created 1 instance of `SomeModel`, so if you do `SomeModel.objects.all()` in the shell, it returns a queryset with that one instance.

If I run this test from vscode's tester it will fail. And when I debug it, I can see `my_model` have two instances of `SomeModel` in the queryset. It does not use a test database, and uses the production database

[image]

When I run this from `python manage.py test my_app.tests` it passes. And it outputs 'Creating test database' and 'Destroying test database' at the start and end of the test respectively. I assume this uses a test database.

How can I make VSCode use a test database for the tests and am I missing something?

Comment: If you try [debug mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests) in testing, will it get the instance?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Yes, the image I posted was the debug mode in testing. I have solved the issue by switching to pytest, though I am still curious if this problem can be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to pytest. Pytest does automatically create a test database for you